# Atomicreference in OSGI DS @Reference

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, declarative-services

I am writing a OSGI application which includes dynamic & static references. Every Service is placed in different bundles.

```
@Reference (bind = "bindMethod", unbind = "unbindMethod", cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private final AtomicReference<TestService> testService = new AtomicReference<TestService>();

@Reference (bind = "bindMethod", unbind = "unbindMethod", cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private AtomicReference<TestService> testService = new AtomicReference<TestService>(); //final is ommitted

 protected void bindMethod(TestService atestService)
    {
        if (TestService.get() == null)
        {
            testService.set(atestService);
        }
    }

    protected void unbindMethod(TestService atestService)
    {
        myServices.compareAndSet(testService, null);
    }
```

Without AtomicReference

```
@Reference (bind = "bindMethod", unbind = "unbindMethod", cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private TestService testService;

protected void bindMethod(TestService atestService)
    {
        testService = atestService;
    }

    protected void unbindMethod(TestService atestService)
    {
        testService = null;
    }
```

Which one is recommended and what is the performance impact of each one?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are putting the @Reference on the field means you are using DS 1.3 with its new field injection support.

In that case you don't need the bind/unbind method nor AtomicReference. Just:

`@Reference
private volatile TestService testService;`

The volatile means that it is a dynamic reference and also provides for proper concurrent access.

Comment: Thanks Hargrave. The service which i am going to use for just start/stop some services. Since there is an Atomic Reference, which uses some sort of concurrency logic internally. What is the need of concurrency/syncrhonization in this ordinary dynamic service? what is the performance impact when i am using AtomicReference and i am not?

Comment: Your comment doesn't seem to be different from the main question, which BJ already answered.

Comment: You don't need to use an AtomicReference. DS will handle managing the value of the field and, since it is volatile, you will have proper concurrency behavior.